# Multiple bugs when trying to display angle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying for a while to get the angle working, but it's not displaying correctly. I get this instead:

[image]

The angle is not correctly labeled. I get the following error messages (all on that line):

> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color "$\theta $"'.
>
> Missing \endcsname inserted. (again)
>
> Runaway argument?
>
> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color "$\theta $"'. (again)
>
> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color "$\theta $"'. (again)

I have no idea how to solve this, the other page I looked at had this work, so I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Enhetscirkeln}
    \label{Enhetscirkeln}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (origo) at (0, 0);
            \draw[gray, thick] (origo) circle (50pt);
            \draw[black, thick] (origo) -- node[above, black, rotate = 30] {$r = 1$} (43.3pt, 25pt) node (r) {};
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (75pt, 0)  node (x) {} node[below]  {$x$};
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (-75pt, 0);
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (0, -75pt);
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (0, 75pt) node[right] {$y$};
            \pic [draw, ->, \dq$\theta$\dq, angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x--origo--r};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know what `\dq` is - it is not working. `quotes` needs to be in quotes like this: `\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x--origo--r};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes,
                babel} % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Enhetscirkeln}
    \label{Enhetscirkeln}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (origo) at (0, 0);
            \draw[gray, thick] (origo) circle (50pt);
            \draw[black, thick] (origo) -- node[above, black, rotate = 30] {$r = 1$} (43.3pt, 25pt) node (r) {};
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (75pt, 0)  node (x) {} node[below]  {$x$};
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (-75pt, 0);
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (0, -75pt);
            \draw[gray, thin, ->] (origo) -- (0, 75pt) node[right] {$y$};
            \pic [draw, ->, 
                  "$\theta$", % <---
                  angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x--origo--r};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Changes in comparison to your MWE (Minimal Working example) are marked by `% <---`.

*Note*:

- package `babel` overwrite meaning of some code in `tikz`. This can be corrected by adding `babel` library to used TikZ libraries.
- command `\dq` is not defined. In above MWE is replaced with `"` as is defined in `quotes` library.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you very much.